# Python run a script as root and /home folder

Tags: python, unix, root

I have a problem with /home folder as root. Here is my script:

```
home = os.path.expanduser("~")
print home             # home is good: /home/guillaume

# gksudo
euid = os.geteuid()
if euid != 0:
    print "Running sudo.."
    args = ['gksudo', sys.executable] + sys.argv + [os.environ]
    os.execlpe('gksudo', *args)
print home            # home has changed: /root
```

How can I get the good /home after gksudo has run ? Thanks

Edit: I've tried

```
subprocess.call(['gksudo', 'script.py'])
```

The script is launched, but the operations inside the script are not in root

Comment: Why gksudo instead of sudo? gksudo is for graphical applications. Is that what you want??

Comment: yes, it's a graphical app, I made a desktop icon in usr/share/application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo` sets a number of environment variables for the process; see `man sudo` for a list. In this case, you can use `SUDO_USER`:

```
# from under sudo
home = os.path.expanduser(os.environ["SUDO_USER"])
```

Comment: Thanks, This is working well. I use this to find the user. After, I add "/home/"

Comment: Do not forget '~' : `os.path.expanduser('~'+os.environ["SUDO_USER"]) `